# How to apply equivalent per column cleanup of delimited file using bash/linux system commands

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, cjk

I have some ruby code that is used to clean up unwanted values that can exist in a customer's input report file (a tab-separated-values file) so it doesn't enter our system for processing.

```rb
  require 'nkf'
  ...
  def clean_value value
    value.gsub!(/[[:space:]]+$/, '')    # remove trailing [[:space:]]
    value.gsub!(/^[[:space:]]+/, '')    # remove leading [[:space:]]
    value.gsub!(/[[:cntrl:]]/, '')      # remove [[:cntrl:]] values 

    # replace japanese full width characters with half width equivalents
    value = NKF.nkf('-X -w', value).tr('０-９ａ-ｚＡ-Ｚ', '0-9a-zA-Z')
    value
  end

  def clean_values values
    # values is an array of fields from TSV row
    values.compact.collect{|value| clean_value(value)}
  end
```

These TSV files can be quite large and I would like to move this down to a system command replacement approach using sed, etc. to speed up processing time.

**1. sed entire file replacement**

I know I can do entire file replacements like this

```
clean.sh
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file=$1
sed -i.bak $'s/\r//g' $file
rm $file.bak
```

But I need to apply the replacements for leading and trailing `[[:space:]]` per column of the TSV, not just per line. Also note, the `[[:space:]]` class is needed to catch oddball whitespace characters that are not found by just using `\s`

**2. Japanese full-width replacement with half-width.**

In my ruby code I am replacing full-width characters found with the half-width equivalents using the NKF gem. Is there an equivalent way to do this using system commands/libraries or do I need to force this clean up operation through a ruby script just for this?

In the end I want the cleaned file to be the same name, same structure, etc.

Comment: Hi, Can you provide the sample data (e.g. TSV).
So I want to try it whether work well. .

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# clear.sh
#-----------------
file=$1

sed -i.bak -e 'y/ａｂｃｄｅｆｇｈｉｊｋｌｍｎｏｐｑｒｓｔｕｖｗｘｙｚＡＢＣＤＥＦＧＨＩＪＫＬＭＮＯＰＱＲＳＴＵＶＷＸＹＺ１２３４５６>７８９０/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890/;s/[[:cntrl:]]+//' ${file} && awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t";OFS="\t"} { for (i=1; i <= NF ; i++)gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/, "", $i); print $0}' ${file} > ${file}_tmp && mv ${file}_tmp ${file}

test -f $file && rm ${file}.bak
```

I hope this will help you. :)

**Ouput examples,** 
The `^I` is tab character.

Input:

```
Frank^IJones^ICalifornia
Sally ^ISmith ^I NＨew York
T６ed^IDanson^IMaine
Harry^ISmith^IOregon
```

Output:

```
Frank^IJones^ICalifornia
Sally^ISmith^INHew York
T6ed^IDanson^IMaine
Harry^ISmith^IOregon
```

Comment: Hi Daein, I may not be able to try it until tomorrow. Its not clear how the replacements for the leading and trailing spaces will operate only on each column vs the entire row. Am I missing something? Each column is separated by a tab - so it can't replace the tabs AND it needs to remove the spaces before and after the text within the column.

Comment: Daein, here is a simple TSV (columns separated by tabs) example where the second row has spaces in some of the columns before or after the text in the column. https://pastebin.com/cK0KK7YN. The actual files don't just have one type of space to remove, they may have any that match the [[:space:]] class code which includes a few oddballs.

Comment: @Streamline I've tried the TSV file for testing. and the output is added above answer.

Comment: reviewing it here only, I don’t see where it is applying the replacement using the `[[:space:]]`

Comment: `FS=" *\t *";OFS="\t" `; input fielder separator is  space* + tab + space*, but ouput separator is only tab.

Comment: It needs to remove all POSIX non printable characters leading or trailing ( hence the [[:space:]] ) not just an actual space

Comment: You want to trim the both side of each column, right?

Comment: Yes - leading and trailing

Comment: `for (i=1; i <= NF ; i++)gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/, "", $i)` this part remove each field leading and trailing [:space:] POSIX class characters. I 
 also edited above answer. You just test it or refer as sample code. It's your turn. :)

Comment: I did some limited testing so far on this and found some flaws: 1)  `s/[[:cntrl:]]+//` incorrectly handles cases where a '+' is the first character in a column because a tab (since tab is a cntrl) as the column separator combined with a '+' matches the expression and in turns removes the column separator and the '+'. 2) The full width to half width expression produces a complaint about mismatched 'y' string length and when trying it by copying pasting it to the terminal, it tries to execute a portion of the string. Perhaps one of the full widths is getting interpreted as a control sequence.

Comment: The actual error message I get from the full width to half width expression you have provided when I run it is: `sed: -e expression #1, char 253: strings for 'y' command are different lengths`

Comment: Since your solution is already using `awk` and operating on the columns after separating, I think moving the `[[:cntrl:]]+` replacement to that portion would work to resolve the case I referred to in my previous comment.

Comment: I am curious if you tested your full width to half width conversion using `sed y///` in your answer because I've been unable to get it working (see previous comments). I tried a similar approach using `tr` with the same arguments and it doesn't throw errors but it mangles other characters such as `°` and `¼`. I think it is missing some prerequisite of unicode either as an option for the command or in the shell/system environment.  The ruby example I use is referencing a library that knows how to handle the unicode characters. I assume a non-ruby solution also needs something similar.